# RX Java - different behaviour of subscribeOn and observeOn

Tags: java, rx-java, observable

I'm new to RX java and I've been experimenting with observeOn and subscribeOn methods. I've read that the difference between them is that they affect the whole chain(subscribeOn) or only the part of the chain after setting a scheduler(observeOn). So why the code below executes fine (prints the current thread):

```
Observable obs = Observable.from(Arrays.asList("element", "2nd element"));
obs.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .map(x -> x.toString().toUpperCase())
                .subscribe(x -> System.out.println("NT:" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + x));
```

while this code doesn't print anything:

```
Observable obs = Observable.from(Arrays.asList("element", "2nd element"));
obs.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .map(x -> x.toString().toUpperCase())
            .subscribe(x -> System.out.println("NT:" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + x));
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `this code doesn't print anything`?

I tried this code:

```
Observable obs = Observable.from(Arrays.asList("element", "2nd element"));
obs.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
  .map(x -> x.toString().toUpperCase())
  .subscribe(x -> System.out.println("NT:" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + x));

Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Output:

> NT:RxNewThreadScheduler-1ELEMENT
>   NT:RxNewThreadScheduler-12ND ELEMENT

Maybe you forgot to `sleep` or do some another work to make application wait for completion of new `RxJava` threads?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, an observable (more specifically, a *cold* observable) is a delayed calculation. So, *.subscribeOn()* defined on which scheduler/thread this calculation will be done, and *.observeOn()* defines on which scheduler/thread you will receive its result. For instance, network request should run on *Schedulers.io* which you specify by adding *.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io)* and you want to display results on main thread by specifying *.observeOn(AndroidShedulers.main)*